# Upload a photo in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a list with photos and I'm using HTML5 and JavaScript to upload a new photo in that list, but I have an issue here. Can anyone help me out in this?

**HTML:**

```
<form action="">
  <input type="file" value="Add new image" id="addPhoto">
</form>

<ul class="list">
   <li><img src="http://https://blog.shareaholic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/shortlink.png" alt="" class="image"></li>
   <li><img src="http://http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" alt="" class="image"></li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function changePhoto(input) {
    if (input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();                
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var source = e.target.results;
            $(".list").append("<li><img src="+source+"></li>");
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
} 

$("#addPhoto").change(function()
    changePhoto(this);
});
```

**CSS*:**

```
.image {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**Demo:** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mwna2d7x/).

Comment: And what's the issue?

Comment: I can't upload a photo. I mean i can upload but i can't show him like 2 previous images.

Comment: Is what you want to do adding the uploaded image in the list after the two images you already have?

Comment: Yeah.That's it exactly

Comment: Check out my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38669091/6313073

Comment: Yeah. Thank you. I'm grateful for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

▶ You haven't loaded **`jQuery`**.

▶ There is no **`FileReader.results`** property.

---

In order to make this work:

▶ Add a recent version of [**`jQuery`**](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js).

▶ Change **`var source = e.target.results;`** to **`var source = e.target.result;`**

---

**jsFiddle:** → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mwna2d7x/2/).

**Snippet:**

```js
function changePhoto(input) {
  if (input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var source = e.target.result;
      $(".list").append("<li><img src=" + source + "></li>")
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#addPhoto").change(function() {
  changePhoto(this);
});
```

```css
.image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="file" value="Add new image" id="addPhoto">
</form>
<ul class="list">
  <li><img src="https://blog.shareaholic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/shortlink.png" alt="" class="image"></li>
  <li><img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" alt="" class="image"></li>
</ul>
```